# Angular get value selection menu for http get request

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working on a website which uses a selection menu. When an item is selected from the menu a HTTP get request should be send to the backend to filter the SQL data with the keyword from the selection menu.

I don't know how to use the value from the selection menu in my http get request. Here is my current code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <select name="Tools" id="Tools" style="width: 900px;">
        <option value="None">Select...</option>
        <option value="Crimping_Pliers">Crimping Pliers</option>
        <option value="Voltage_Tester">Voltage Tester</option>
        <option value="Waterpump_Pliers">Waterpump Pliers</option>
        <option value="Cable_Cutter">Cable Cutter</option>
        <option value="Diagonal_Cutter">Diagonal Cutter</option>
        <option value="Stripping_Tool">Stripping Tool</option>
        <option value="Stripping_Tool_Set">Stripping Tool Set</option>
        <option value="Stripping_Tool_Holder">Stripping Tool Holder</option>
        <option value="Combination_Pliers">Combination Pliers</option>
        <option value="Needle_Nose_Pliers">Needle Nose Pliers</option>
        <option value="Stanley_Knife">Stanley Knife</option>
        <option value="Drill_Set">Drill Set</option>
        <option value="Screwdriver">Screwdriver</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

So currently I need to use the value from the options to filter the SQL data (or make a specific request).

So now I need to create a function which sends a get request with the value from the selection menu.
I do this in typescript. But I don't know how to acces the wanted values. How do I do this?

Here is my get request:

```
filterList(){
this.http.get(this.rootURL + 'Users' + '/value from selection menu')
.toPromise()
.then(res => this.list = res as UserDetail[])
}
```

Comment: Just bind a change event to the select and in the type script file create that method to make a get call.

Comment: add your typescript ;)

Comment: @GaganDeep Thank you for your reply, but how do I get the value from the selection menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your TS file you can take one variable like `optionValue`

and then in your html template

```
<select name="Tools" id="Tools" style="width: 900px;"  (change)="myFunction($event)">
        <option value="None">Select...</option>
        <option value="Crimping_Pliers">Crimping Pliers</option>
        <option value="Voltage_Tester">Voltage Tester</option>
        <option value="Waterpump_Pliers">Waterpump Pliers</option>
        <option value="Cable_Cutter">Cable Cutter</option>
        <option value="Diagonal_Cutter">Diagonal Cutter</option>
        <option value="Stripping_Tool">Stripping Tool</option>
        <option value="Stripping_Tool_Set">Stripping Tool Set</option>
        <option value="Stripping_Tool_Holder">Stripping Tool Holder</option>
        <option value="Combination_Pliers">Combination Pliers</option>
        <option value="Needle_Nose_Pliers">Needle Nose Pliers</option>
        <option value="Stanley_Knife">Stanley Knife</option>
        <option value="Drill_Set">Drill Set</option>
        <option value="Screwdriver">Screwdriver</option>
    </select>
```

and define this function in your TS file like:

```
myFunction(event) {
    let optionValue = event.target.value
    console.log(optionValue)
}
```

you can also make your function parameterized like

```
filterList(option){
this.http.get(`${this.rootURL}/Users/${option}`)
.toPromise()
.then(res => this.list = res as UserDetail[])
}
```

and call above function from `myfunction` with giving option value